# Error occurs when I try to open json file in jupyter

Tags: json, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to use the with statement, open the Wikipedia JSON file to be read into the variable file, and use json.load() to save the data to a new variable.

But I fave with the error provided in pic.

Can someone help?

I am trying to use the with statement, open the Wikipedia JSON file to be read into the variable file

Comment: ['Can somebody help me?' is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/11107541). Can you please ask an actual question? You can see [ask] for guidance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

just found the answer :)

in case if someone will have a similar problem make sure to follow this path after with open statement:
with open(f'{file_dir}/folder-name/file-name.json', mode='r') as file